# I want to extract a certain dates from the calendar IN PYTHON please

Tags: python, date, calendar

I want to extract a certain dates from the calendar. For example, given the start date is 02/01/2017 and that day happens to be a Monday, I want to add the date to an empty list and if day in (Mon to Thurs), I want to add 8 days to that date and add that date to the list. If friday, add 3 days to the list.

Put it simply, if start date is monday, next tuesday, wednesday after that week and the thursday after and then friday ... each week, increment the day and add it to the list but if friday, add monday's date to the list.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm still on the verge of trying to figure out where to start, i've tried importing date time and finding out todays day and then reversing back to add 7 days to the date but dont think that'll work

Answer (score 0):

The pandas package isn't necessary, but if you ever need to input a date via raw_input(), it is a good tool for handling formatting issues with just one line of code. (2016/12/12 vs. 12-12-16, etc.)

If I understand your question correctly, this should accomplish what you want:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

dates = []
start_date = pd.to_datetime(raw_input('Enter Start Date: '))
dates.append(start_date.strftime('%x'))

if start_date.weekday() < 4:
    add_date = start_date + timedelta(8)
    dates.append(add_date.strftime('%x'))
elif start_date.weekday() == 4:
    add_date = start_date + timedelta(3)
    dates.append(add_date.strftime('%x'))
else:
    print 'Error: Start Date is on a weekend.'

print dates
```

Comment: For some reason i keep getting stupid errors like 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' but this helped me soo much! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes, knowing the data type is always important because they have different built-in functions. `strftime` is a function of datetime objects. A datetime object is numerical, so strftime converts the object into a string, given the format string provided. For instance, '%x' makes the datetime show up as 12/12/2016 format. Visit [http://strftime.org/](http://strftime.org/) for more info on format strings.